# Implementing interfaces in Erlang

Tags: interface, erlang

How does one implement an interface in erlang? What is the structure of the modules or how is it setup?

I have a layered architecture and want to implement the interfaces in each layer. Allowing the layer which requires the below layer to handle some task to access or call for these tasks.

How would this interface module look in terms of functionality?

Comment: what is your Erlang level? Do you need general help in writing module (exported function etc), good practices (one module grouping API to some application) or pros & cons of otp behaviours?

Comment: If the layers you are talking about are layers in a protocol stack you might have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059746/how-to-design-a-flexible-erlang-protocol-stack-creation-api BUT be aware that this is about very specific requirements that seem to make a more complicated than usual approach.  Unfortunately not much discussion going on there ... more or less talking with myself ;-)

Comment: To give a good answer to your question some more information might be necessary.  What exactly do you mean with interface?

Comment: I mean, an interface which allows modules to access modules or process on a lower level. Exactly what an interface in architecture means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An *interface* in the sense of a Java interface or an ML module signature does not exist in the dynamically typed Erlang world. You will have to document the behavior in a comment or provide a -spec contract for the dialyzer to look at.

In general, the best way to approach a language is by not presuming you can map your existing knowledge too much into it, unless you happen to know a language that is "close" in concepts. Languages close to Erlang are Prolog and Scheme. Farther out comes Python and Ruby, but their reliance on an OOP design puts them into the horizon. Anything statically typed, Ocaml, Haskell, Java, C#, C++ and so on are definitely beyond the horizon.

Answer (score -2):

The closest concept in Erlang is [user-defined behaviour](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/spec_proc.html#id68495). However, they tend to be used quite rarely. Note that the only thing which is checked is existence and arity of functions. You *can't* test that the module actually implements some behaviour; you just call the callback functions and if the module happens to "accidentally" export functions with same names, you are out of luck.

Comment: No! Behaviours are NOT interfaces. They're made to separate generic, well-behaved code from specific, risky modules (your code). They denote a module taking over yours for the handling of some tasks, not just the concept of a callback.

Comment: Adding my more acidic voice to IGTA's, please stop trying to map OOP concepts onto Erlang constructs.  It's a bad mapping and it will make your comprehension of Erlang go slower.  Learn what Erlang **is**, not what you'd like it to be.

Comment: @ I GIVE TERRIBLE ADVICE. I went through your Erlang lessons when I started with Erlang. Nice Work :) Are interfaces not needed in Erlang or what do you mean? Thanks

Comment: A module's exported functions give its own API. Type annotations can be given by using specs and types (http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html) and tools like Dialyzer will pick them up. But otherwise, there is no other tool to say "these two modules agree to a given contract" in the way you mean it. You just have to work without them, which is quite doable.

Comment: Behavior =/= Interface, that is for sure. However, students of ML will notice some similarities.