# Erlang polymorphism: multiple implementations of the same contract?

Tags: erlang, polymorphism

What's correct Erlang way to have separated implementations from the contract and how to switch between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While others mention the *behaviour* feature, it is merely a small helper to make sure you implement all functions in a module for a callback structure. If you have two implementations, `a` and `b`, and both implements the same functions, you can just statically substitute `a` for `b` in a calling module. For static configuration where you have a better implementation, this is preferable.

If the question is of a more dynamic nature, you can just do

```
 Mod = a,
 Mod:f(Args).
```

And then in code set `Mod` appropriately. This lets you dynamically control what module to call while the program is running. It is not entirely clear which of the two you want.

Comment: yeah - in the first half of your comment is what I was looking for - so now I'm sure about it - but could you please elaborate that second part - what do you mean by 'more dynamic nature' as I don't understand how can I rebind Mod after once has been bound during run-time due to single assignment ... just didn't get it I assume ... thanks!

Comment: Suppose `Mod` is given as a parameter to a function. Now the code calling `Mod:f(Args)` is dynamic because we can vary the parameter to get different program behaviour. Typically, you shove the `Mod` into a `#state{ implementation = Mod, ...}` record and then use this to get dynamic calls. Do note: you can't `grep(1)` in the code base and the dialyzer has a harder time figuring out the call structure. These are the sacrifices you make for such a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Nice example of polymorphism is `qlc` module and structure `table`. See various `M:table/1,2` implementations in `ets`, `dets`, `mnesia` and so. Try `ets:table(ets:new(foo, [set])).` in shell for example and look into `qlc` documentation and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Since Erlang is dynamically typed, [function guards](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id80117) (the `when … ->` bits) are the way to express polymorphism.

E.g:

```
len (T) when is_tuple(T) -> size(T);
len (L) when is_list(L) -> length(L).
```

Comment: I'm looking for way how to separate contract and implementation - something like: M1,M2 that implements some contract C - where in M1 there is C implemented using one technology and M2 using other ... something like that ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look on [behaviours](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/des_princ.html#id64008) concept. At least for me there is small similarity to OOP in terms of having interface definition and multiple implementation modules.

Comment: yup - thanks - I saw something about it here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119477/implementing-interfaces-in-erlang) but I'm just not sure if behaviors might be used for this purpose - I agree not to map OOP onto Erlang constructs - but I find the requirement to have such separation legal so trying to figure out how to do it properly ... thank for hints anyways!

Answer (score 0):

If I realized your question, here is example for approach, that pretty much works for me. This approach helps to separate interface and implementation.

"Interface" module.

```
-module(contract).

-export([
    new/2,
    do_something/2
]).


%% Behavioural callbacks definition. Each of "derived" modules should implement it.
-callback new(Arg :: any()) -> {ok, ImplState :: any()} | {error, Reason :: atom()}.
-callback do_something( Arg :: any(), ImplState :: any() ) -> {ok, ReturnVal :: any(), NewImplState :: any()} | {error, Reason :: atom()}.


%% Opaque state to hold implementation details
-record(
    contract_impl, {
        impl_module :: module(),
        impl_state  :: any()
    }
).


%% Interface for creation "polymorphic" instance, like base-class constructor.
new(ImplModule, ImplInitArgs) ->
  case ImplModule:new(ImplInitArgs) of
    {ok, State} ->
      {ok,
        #contract_impl {
          impl_module = ImplModule,
          impl_state = State
        }
      };
    {error, Reason} ->
      {error, Reason}
  end.

%% Interface function, like an abstract method in OOP.
do_something(
  Arg,
  #contract_impl {
    impl_module = ImplModule,
    impl_state = ImplState
  } = ContractImpl
) ->
  case ImplModule:do_something(Arg, ImplState) of
    {ok, ReturnVal, NewState} ->
      {ok, ReturnVal, ContractImpl#contract_impl{ impl_state = NewState }};
    {error, Reason} -> {error, Reason}
  end.
```

Some implementation example (like derived class).

```
-module(foo).

-behaviour(contract).

-export([
  new/1,
  do_something/2
]).

-record(
  foo_state, {
    repeat_count
  }
).

new(Options) ->
  {ok,
    #foo_state{
      repeat_count = proplists:get_value(repeat_count, Options)
    }
  }.

do_something(Arg, #foo_state{ repeat_count = RepeatCount } = State) ->
  Result = [ io_lib:format("Foo ~p", [Arg]) || _Index <- lists:seq(1, RepeatCount) ],
  {ok, Result, State}.
```

Now you can do the following:

```
usage_example() ->
  {ok, State} = contract:new(foo, [{repeat_count, 15}]),
  {ok, Result, NewState} = contract:do_something("bar", State),
  ok.
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks alot for effort Viacheslav! this is almost it - just how to avoid that state in it (cause what I really want avoid is to apply OOP principles in erlang) - basically what I have in mind it just to enforce implementation to implement contract's functions and let some other mechanisms to use concrete modules - anyways thanks for pointing me to the behaviors - as I see it now - I'd separate state into processes and functions under concrete behaviors - and let pattern matching and guards handle polymorphism - do I think correct about it? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: I'm not sure that I got what you want :) Generally it is good idea to pass some state into function call and return new one as part of return result. I see no reason to avoid it. Of course, you can hide some state in separate process beneath your implementation, but you should think twice before doing that. As I see, it can make your code hard for testing and debugging.

Comment: by state I mean "object state" in this case - my main point in this thread is to think about modules "design" and code/contract separation :) anyways - I have now enough clues what to think about next - thanks for hints!